# EasyAdminBundle - Custom Block for show view

Tags: symfony, symfony2-easyadmin

I'm using the EasyAdminBundle for SF and I have a show view for an Entity, where I list like id, username and password. What I would like to do is simply render one more row where I deliver the content from a custom template.

what is the easiest way? I didn't found a solution yet with YAML. Do I need to overwrite the whole `show.html.twig` ?

Comment: Have you read the bundle doc about "virtual properties" ? 

If you really need to call another template then I think you need to overwite the show.html.twig

Comment: Yes, and actually not a bad idea, but I feel that as a huge hack. You should imagine like under the user I would like to show the gravatar Image for a user. That's not a propery for my user object. Maybe it's a bad example but I hope you get what I  mean

Comment: I get what you mean, But I've already used virtual properties and it works fine. The virtual property I implemented was not just a simple form field, but a complex html array with statistics from the database. 

I've also already overrided the show.html.twig template and I feel virtual properties is more simple to implement.